# Non-conservative electromagnetic fields $ \displaystyle \nabla \times \vec{E} = - \frac {\partial \vec{B} }{\partial t}. $

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

While studying electromagnetism, I came across the statement

$$  \displaystyle \oint_{\delta S} \vec{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{l} = \frac {\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \iint _{S} \vec{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S} \, $$

which explains the concept of the non conservative electric field. I searched for this here on this site and that for an electric field to be conservative $ \displaystyle \nabla \times \vec{E} = 0 .$

Here it shows curl of Electric field, but I am not clear about curl of a vector field.

The relation for curl here is $ \displaystyle \nabla \times \vec{E} = - \frac {\partial \vec{B} }{\partial t}. $ (I may be wrong here, cause I am not clear with the topic.)

---

$1.$ Why does a non conservative field arise (I am interested in molecular explanation) ? I would like if someone provide me with a good source.

$ 2.$ How can I physically visualise curl? (I know it's literal meaning but am unable to visualise.)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a "molecular explanation"?

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi [About drawing geometric shapes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333023/how-can-i-draw-geometric-shapes-in-my-question)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)

Comment: It means what is happening at the atomic scale that give rise to the non-conserved electric field.

Comment: I read that electric field make closed loops, thus we cannot talk about potential, but why only closed loops?

Comment: Re. "How can I physically visualise curl?" – you might want to check out this [video](https://youtu.be/rB83DpBJQsE) by 3b1b which explains divergence and curl conceptually.

Comment: You may want to read the wikipedia article on the Maxwell equations.

Comment: Comments pruned: some about previous versions of the question, some that just said "thank you," and some that should have been posted as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm a bit unsure about what you mean by "molecular explanation". You may think that some type of molecules are responsible for conservative fields? That is not the case. Conservative fields are created when you have a changing magnetic field $\frac{\partial B}{dt}$. The two equations you wrote

$$  \displaystyle \oint_{\delta S} \vec{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{l} = \frac {\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \iint _{S} \vec{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S} \, $$

$$ \displaystyle \nabla \times \vec{E} = - \frac {\partial \vec{B} }{\partial t}. $$

are Faraday's law in integral and differential form. To understand this better imagine you have a loop where a magnetic field changes with time (for this case let's say it increases with time so that $I$ always point in the same direction). With a change in magnetic flux $\frac{d\phi_B}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\int \vec{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S}$ you can see that an electromotive force $\varepsilon =\oint \vec E \cdot \vec{dl}\neq 0$ will be induced in the loop. Now what does this mean? The fact that this closed loop integral is not zero $\oint \vec E \cdot \vec {dl}\neq 0$ is what makes it a non-conservative field. There is nothing "physical" about it.

[image]

2. You can visualize curl by mathematical programs such as GeoGebra. Curl is how much the vector field rotates at a specific point. See example this picture from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#/media/File:Uniform_curl.svg). If you want to see curl even more physically than this then try taking a glass of water and put a spoon in and spin it around. Now you will observe curl in the form of velocity field in your glass of water.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I am clear with the concept of the Non-conservative electric fields, But am still confused about CURL. Like why we need to define this ? I know it's literal meaning that it is a vector in the direction of the torque in infinitesimal small elements of a vector field ( Here in your example is the velocity field).  But what is its use ?

Comment: What is the use for curl? Or why do we define curl? Without curl one could not formulate Farday's law in differential form or Ampere-Maxwell law. As soon as you have rotation at a point in a vector field then curl gives the information of how this rotation looks. I bet you can come up with a bunch of fields where rotation exist. One example is the magnetic field which has only curl (it's divergence free). Another example would be the flow of some liquid going down a drain.

Comment: Thanks I get it. I thought there was something hidden which I missed. Now it is all clear.